# IMPORTRANGE: value missing?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have been working on this issue for a few weeks now and can't seem to find a solution. I used this answer ([IMPORTRANGE with CONDITIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679844/importrange-with-conditions)) to get as far as I could, but I keep getting a value error.

This is [the sheet I'm working with](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QFbzMmeY5Ck0a_uOzf4Oae_l2HCk0C_lXcYoJAiG9QM).

My goal is to use the first tab in the sheet (`All Games`) to enter all the games that I come across to create a compendium. But, then I want it to automatically populate the other tabs based on certain criteria (what type of game, skills learned, etc.)

On the `Warm-Ups` tab you'll see the formulas I have tried. A1 is the most recent.

Here is the formula I tried:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F64PMg_iFu-DaJAUaE4BkpqF4zoteknp56VfwAUe8ag/edit#gid=1359689553", "All Games!A1:A1300"),"SELECT Col1 WHERE (Col2 = 'w') ")
```

I am getting a value error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to reference **Col2** but you selected range **A1:A1300** which is just **1** column. therefore try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1F64PMg_iFu-DaJAUaE4BkpqF4zoteknp56VfwAUe8ag", "All Games!A1:B1300"),
 "SELECT Col1 WHERE (Col2 = 'w') ")
```

from the brief look on your sheet, you may want use **`matches`** or **`contains`** instead of **`=`** in your `QUERY`

Comment: Okay, that at least returned a value. But, it seems it is pulling only the criteria that matches all of those in the equation. So, using the equation you gave it will give me the column header text of the row that matches the criteria I put for the =. 

So, let's say I want to pull all the games that have "Warm Up" in column E, and have them compiled in that Warm-Up tab. 

How could I do that?

Comment: Is it the "Col1" that is the problem? Should it be "Row1" or does Col1 mean that it is a row?

Comment: you use "contains" like: `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1F64PMg_iFu-DaJAUaE4BkpqF4zoteknp56VfwAUe8ag", "All Games!A1:B1300"),
 "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 contains 'Warm Up' ")` query doesnt work with rows Col means column

Comment: warm up is in column 5 so: `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1F64PMg_iFu-DaJAUaE4BkpqF4zoteknp56VfwAUe8ag", "All Games!A1:E1300"), "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col5 contains 'Warm Up' ")`

Comment: It says it will overwrite data in A22?

Comment: well, delete A22,A23 and A24 otherwise query cant be enrolled

Comment: or put your formula in B column

Comment: I feel so dumb. I didn't realize it was referring to the data on that sheet. 

Okay, making progress. I just created a new tab to experiment with. When I entered the formula I now get:

A
Difficulty
1
1
1
1
1
etc.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F64PMg_iFu-DaJAUaE4BkpqF4zoteknp56VfwAUe8ag/edit#gid=560020245

Comment: To clarify, I want it to pull the entire row that matches the criteria.

Comment: check your sheet

Comment: `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1F64PMg_iFu-DaJAUaE4BkpqF4zoteknp56VfwAUe8ag", "All Games!A1:I"), "SELECT * WHERE Col5 contains 'Warm Up' ")`

Comment: btw. not sure if you rly need importrange... `=QUERY('All Games'!A1:I, "SELECT * WHERE Col5 contains 'Warm Up' ")`

Comment: AH! THANK YOU! Brilliant. That is absolutely perfect. I had tried QUERY, but obviously I was doing it wrong. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are only importing (part of) ColumnA - so no wonder Google can't find a second column :)

Comment: Ah, yeah! I see that. ;P 
Thank you.